# Bulk import of notes with attachment - MIME type important

Tags: import, dynamics-crm-2011, mime-types, dynamics-crm-2013

we want to import almost 1000 annotations with attachments. I tried to import without a MIME type delivered and everything worked fine, but when I was looking in the database I saw the MIME type of every attachment is "application/octet-stream", also for images (jpg,gif,png) and PDFs.

My question is: Is the MIME Type important or can we ignore it?

If it is important can we use this assignment (taken from database after manual import): 
jpg -> image/jpeg 
doc -> application/octet-stream
docx -> application/octet-stream
pdf -> application/pdf
msg -> application/octet-stream
htm -> text/html
png -> image/png
gif -> image/png
xls -> application/octet-stream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: The MIME type of attachments is not important, it can be ignored.

All attachments are encoded and stored in the database as application/octet-stream, irregardless of how they got there.

Have a look here: 
https://organizationURL.com/XRMServices/2011/OrganizationData.svc/ActivityMimeAttachmentSet

You should not be able to find any attachments that do not have

```xml
<d:MimeType>application/octet-stream</d:MimeType>
```